# Downloading excel file from server with weird character C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel, asp.net-mvc-5, openxml-sdk

*Hi all,*

I have a problem that I generate excel file on server (.NET OpenXML SDK 2.5) and write to MemoryStream. Then write array byte of MemoryStream to Response header to client.

But on client side parse error cause encoding file with bom, I think.

I would appreciate it if you help me. Thanks.
So here is my code:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ExportExcel(string fileName, System.Data.DataTable dataTable, Dictionary<string, string> headers, string[] groupBy = null)
{
    try
    {
        if (groupBy == null)
        {
            string absolutePath = ExportExcelWithoutGroupBy(fileName, dataTable, headers);
            byte[] filebytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(absolutePath);

            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(filebytes))
            {
                Response.Clear();
                Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
                Response.Charset = "";
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format(@"attachment; filename={0}", absolutePath));
                Response.AddHeader("content-length", Convert.ToString(stream.Length));
                //stream.Position = 0;
                //stream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
                Response.BinaryWrite(stream.ToArray());
                Response.Flush();
                Response.End();
                return null;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            //not implemented yet
            return Json(new { Status = "Unsupported" }, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
        }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          throw ex;
      }
}

private static string ExportExcelWithoutGroupBy(string fileName, System.Data.DataTable dataTable, Dictionary<string, string> headers)
{
    SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = null;
    try
    {
         string absolutePath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(@"/ExcelReport/" + fileName + ".xlsx");

         if (System.IO.File.Exists(absolutePath))
         {
             System.IO.File.Delete(absolutePath);
         }

         uint sheetId = 1;

         //create SpreadsheetDocument follow on filePath.
         //default parameter AutoSave = true, Editable = true, and Type = xlsx.
         spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.
         Create(absolutePath, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);

         // add WorkbookPart (excel file) to SpreadsheetDocument.
         WorkbookPart workbookpart = spreadsheetDocument.AddWorkbookPart();
         workbookpart.Workbook = new Workbook();

         // add WorksheetPart (sheet) to WorkbookPart (excel).
         var worksheetPart = workbookpart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
         worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet();

         // create Sheets in excel
         Sheets sheets;
         sheets = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.Workbook.
                                                   AppendChild<Sheets>(new Sheets());

         //define style (css) in excel
         WorkbookStylesPart stylesPart = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorkbookStylesPart>();
         stylesPart.Stylesheet = GenerateStyleSheet();
         stylesPart.Stylesheet.Save();

         //create sheetData to insert data in a sheet
         var sheetData = new SheetData();

         // add new sheet in array sheets
         var sheet = new Sheet()
         {
             Id = spreadsheetDocument.WorkbookPart.
                    GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart),
             SheetId = sheetId,
             Name = fileName + "_" + DateTime.Today.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")
         };
         sheets.Append(sheet); //push new sheet

         //add row header
         AddRowHeader(worksheetPart, sheetData, headers);

         //add rows data from DataTable
         AddRowsDataDetail(worksheetPart, sheetData, headers, dataTable);

         workbookpart.Workbook.Save();

         return absolutePath;
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         throw ex;
     }
     finally
     {
         spreadsheetDocument.Close();
     }
}
```

On client side

```
$.ajax({
     url: "/SupportMainPage/Utils/ExportExcel",
     data: { "fileName": "ExcelFile", "jsonData": JSON.stringify(srcSource), "headers": headers },
     type: 'POST',
     contentType: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
     async: false,
     success: function (result) {
         debugger      
     },
     error: function (xhr, textStatus, throwException) {
         //here what I receive 
         //textStatus: parseerror
         //xhr.responseText: "Invalid XML: PK�YQIm�w��,xl/workbook.xml �(���An�0E�b�>�N)M�$l���T���ن�n,z�^�.����������/_�v�;cL�Br%�a�d\8�pʶj`;tK�I��':��R��0�<��'=�WiE3��Y�^�r�OsDe҈���k!6�+�����?ł��Ç|���j!7����)T�b���5�Ҋ�y}�Y���;N�Y�4��>y��qR�LO��0>t�����PK↵�YQI��,((_rels/.rels �(�<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships">...
         debugger
     }
});
```

**Updated:**

On server side:

```
Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
```

On client side:

```
$.ajax({
 url: "/SupportMainPage/Utils/ExportExcel",
 data: { "fileName": "ExcelFile", "jsonData": JSON.stringify(srcSource), "headers": headers },
 type: 'POST',
 async: false,
 success: function (result) {
     var file = new Blob([result], { type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;' });
     var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
     window.open(fileURL);
 },
 error: function (xhr, textStatus, throwException) {
     //here what I receive 
     //textStatus: parseerror
     //xhr.responseText: "Invalid XML: PK�YQIm�w��,xl/workbook.xml �(���An�0E�b�>�N)M�$l���T���ن�n,z�^�.����������/_�v�;cL�Br%�a�d\8�pʶj`;tK�I��':��R��0�<��'=�WiE3��Y�^�r�OsDe҈���k!6�+�����?ł��Ç|���j!7����)T�b���5�Ҋ�y}�Y���;N�Y�4��>y��qR�LO��0>t�����PK↵�YQI��,((_rels/.rels �(�<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Relationships xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships">...
     debugger
 }
});
```

The code above has downloaded file, but excel file corrupted and couldn't be opened.

Answer (score 0):

Your xhr.responseText is a xlsx file - which is a ZIP archive with specific file layout internally. It is not a valid XML file in any way.

Most likely you should be triggering a download of the file in a hidden iframe, rather than trying to receive it as an AJAX response.

Comment: What should I do to get xlsx file from server?